# Sprint Board and org-super-agenda : problems with DONE tasks

Tags: org-agenda, org-ql, org-super-agenda

I am constructing a sprint board using a custom agenda view using org-super-agenda.  It works really quite well with a couple exceptions, namely:

1. Dates: I want to use variables (or constants) for the sprint start and end dates, defined "somewhere else", that will get used in the `org-agenda-custom-command` block to limit the scope of the view to within those dates, and
2. `DONE` tasks: I want any tasks `DONE` in the sprint period to show up in the `DONE block`.  Right now, they only show up for `DONE` tasks that have a `SCHEDULED` date of today.

How might this be accomplished?  I can post my code if that is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I found something which does almost exactly what I want, albeit not as an agenda command.  The code that does it:

```
(org-ql-search (org-agenda-files)
  '(ts-active :from "2022-04-25" :to "2022-05-08")
  :title "Sprint Period"
  :sort '(priority date)
  :super-groups '((:log t)
           (:name "Schedule" :time-grid t)
           (:name "Today" :scheduled today)
           (:name "DOING" :todo
              ("DOING"))
           (:name "TODO" :todo
              ("TODO"))
           (:name "DONE" :todo
              ("DONE"))
           (:name "PROJ" :todo
              ("PROJ"))))
```

I run this search and it generates what I want.  The search is not persistent across Emacs sessions, I solved that by running `org-store-link` in the search result buffer, and then pasting that link into the body of a daily task.  Clicking on that link regenerates the search result view.  Also, I can edit the link once every two weeks to enter the dates for a new sprint.

Still interested in a way to do this with a agenda custom command, meaning less typing and clicking.  Everything I read indicates that `org-agenda` will only show `DONE` tasks if the current day matches either the date closed or the date scheduled.